# Powershell VSCode invoke-command from localhost different user for SCCM

Tags: powershell, authentication, sccm, invoke-command

Because VSCode is not able to run a powershell console and debug it as a different user i am trying to get arround it with invoked credentials like this:

```
Start-Service -Name "WinRM"
$cred = Get-Credential -Credential domain\myuser
Invoke-command -Credential $cred -Computer "localhost" -scriptblock {

    Import-Module "$($ENV:SMS_ADMIN_UI_PATH)\..\ConfigurationManager.psd1"
    Set-Location 'XXX:' # my sccm site code
    Import-CMComputerInformation -CollectionName "All Systems" -ComputerName "TestComputer" -MacAddress "00:00:00:00:00:69"

}
```

If i start it in the debugger of VSCode (F5) it starts but cant connect then to the SCCM Server infrastructure. Could someone help me to solve this issue?

Error:

```
Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'XXX' does not exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (XXX:String) [Set-Location], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost

This command cannot be run from the current drive. To run this command you must first connect to a Configuration Manager drive.
    + CategoryInfo          : DeviceError: (Microsoft.Confi...ormationCommand:ImportComputerInformationCommand) [Import-CMComputerInformation], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandCannotExecuteFromCurrentDrive,Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.Cmdlets.Oob.Commands.ImportComputerInformationCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

If i logoff from my machine and login with my admin credentials and execute everything in the invoke-command scriptblock it works.
As i am not allowed to work like this by our company policy's is there maybe a alternative way or something i can do to use the visual studio code debugger?

Comment: what happens when you start vscode by running it as a different user? (right click "run as administrator" or shift + rightclick "run as different user" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you logged onto the SCCM site server interactively with the credentials you are using and opened the console at least once? I believe this initial first opening is required before the drive is accessible remotely...

Comment: Hi , thanks a lot.... its a freshly imaged machine and i never had open the sccm console on this machine. This was causing the issue. I added a new option that i start the console first once with the specific user credentials.